# SET COOKIE PHP using REQUEST_URI and then output without refreshing page

Tags: php, html, if-statement, cookies, request-uri

I'm hoping one you bright sparks can help me. I have a simple PHP script that will output a different telephone number based on the fact if the URL they access contains a certain query string. This allows me to track phone calls easier when using Adwords.

So, the idea is if they access the site and the url has a query string xyz in it, it sets a cookie value with expire, and for that duration it displays a different telephone number. The problem is on the first page load the php is not reading the cookie value.

When a person visits `example.com/?dynamic=keyword&abc=xyz` it stores a cookie and the page should read the alternative number.

This is the code I have set in the `<head>`

```
<head>
<?php 
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xyz') !== false ){
    $value = 'adwords_visit';
    setcookie("adwords_customer", $value);
    setcookie("adwords_customer", $value, time()+604800);
    setcookie("adwords_customer", $value, time()+604800, "/");
} 
?>
</head>
```

This is the code I use in the `<body>`

```
<body>
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['adwords_customer']) && ($_COOKIE['adwords_customer'] == true)){ ?>
    <a onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('tel:1111');" href="tel:1111" title="Call Us">1111</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="tel:2222" title="Call Us">2222</a>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

The above code works but the values only update on the page after a page refresh. Is there a way of doing this without having to use JavaScript?

Comment: Cookies created with setcookie are available on the next page load. Note that you should call setcookie before the <head> tag or any other page output.

Comment: Can you not simply set a boolean, or are the head and body rendered in different scopes?

Comment: @MikeC I did put REQUEST_URI above all the HTML at the very top of everything but no difference. The site uses WordPress so the `header.php` containers the setting of the cookie and later in the `header.php` it uses `<?php get_template_part('the-telephone-numbers-code'); ?>` I've tried it without get_template_part and just having it as the code supplied above.

Comment: I'm not familiar with wordpress, but if there is some sort of variable you could set in the header, in addition to setting the cookie, then in the body you could check for the existence of the cookie OR the variable.